# Apply css rules in php condition

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I add some custom stock status messages on WooCommerce with some PHP code like this :

```
    //Ajoute "En stock" sous chaque produit
function show_stock() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) { // if manage stock is enabled 
        if (( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') > 0 ) && ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') < 100 )) { // if in stock
            echo '<div class="remaining" style="color:green;">En stockk</div>';
        } elseif (( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') >= 100 ) && ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') < 1000 )) {
            echo '<div class="remaining" style="color:#f2cd00;">Livraison sous 1 mois</div>';
        } elseif (( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') >= 1000 ) && ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') < 2000 )) {
            echo '<div class="remaining" style="color:#f2cd00;">Livraison sous 7 jours</div>';
        } elseif ( number_format($product->get_stock_quantity(),0,'','') < 1 ) {
            echo '<div class="remaining" style="color:red;">Rupture</div>'; 
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','show_stock', 10);
add_action ('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','show_stock');
```

And i apply this CSS rule for make disappear the default WooCoomerce stock message in my single product page and avoid double stock status messages.

```
p.stock{
    display: none;
}
```

The Problem that i have is my PHP code not working anymore when stock = 0 and then my last conditional of php code isn't apply (not showing my custom message "Rupture").

And because i applied my CSS rule when my stock = 0 i have no stock status.

Then i would like to apply my CSS rule only when my stock > 0.
Or
Find way to make apply my last conditional php for stock < 1.

:'( thank you

Comment: It is not the intention to add inline CSS in PHP/HTML code. Inline CSS is dirty because it takes away some of the flexibility. Via PHP/HTML you can add an `ID` or a `CLASS` and then adjust it via a style sheet.

Comment: There's no `<p style="stock">` or equivalent generated in the php code you provided. Can you give us more detail about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Very Odd to be doing a `number_format()` which is for presentation as part of a value test

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to add a custom stock message. Next, you are going to hide the default WooCommerce stock message with CSS. Why not immediately overwrite the default WooCommerce stock message with your own message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code shows how to change text & class, both on the *Single product page* + add html on the *Shop/Category page*

In this way you can adjust or add your custom availability text/class.

> P.s the code could be shorter but has been extended so that you can clearly see which adjustment is made where.

---

> **`woocommerce_get_availability_text`** - Change availability text - *Single product page*
>
> **`woocommerce_get_availability_class`** - Change availability class - *Single product page*
>
> **`woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`** - Add html - *Shop/Category page*

---

**PHP:** Add to `functions.php`

```php
// Change availability text - Single product page
function change_stock_text( $text, $product ) { 
    // Managing stock enabled
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {

        // Get stock status
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if ( $stock_quantity == 0 ) {
            $text = __( 'Text 1', 'woocommerce' );
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1 && $stock_quantity < 100 ) {
            $text = __( 'Text 2', 'woocommerce' );          
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 100 && $stock_quantity < 1000 ) {
            $text = __( 'Text 3', 'woocommerce' );          
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1000 && $stock_quantity < 2000 ) {
            $text = __( 'Text 4', 'woocommerce' );          
        } else {
            $text = __( 'Text 5', 'woocommerce' );          
        }
    }

    // Output
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'change_stock_text', 10, 2 );

// Change availability class - Single product page
function change_stock_class( $class, $product ) {   
    // Managing stock enabled
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {

        // Get stock status
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if ( $stock_quantity == 0 ) {
            $class = 'custom-stock-green';
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1 && $stock_quantity < 100 ) {
            $class = 'custom-stock-orange';         
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 100 && $stock_quantity < 1000 ) {
            $class = 'custom-stock-orange';         
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1000 && $stock_quantity < 2000 ) {
            $class = 'custom-stock-red';            
        } else {
            $class = 'custom-stock-some-color';     
        }
    }

    // Output    
    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_class', 'change_stock_class', 10, 2 );

// Add html - Shop/Category page
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    global $product;

    // Managing stock enabled
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {

        // Get stock status
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if ( $stock_quantity == 0 ) {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-green">' . __( 'Text 1', 'woocommerce' );
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1 && $stock_quantity < 100 ) {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-orange">' . __( 'Text 2', 'woocommerce' );      
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 100 && $stock_quantity < 1000 ) {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-orange">' . __( 'Text 3', 'woocommerce' );  
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1000 && $stock_quantity < 2000 ) {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-orange">' . __( 'Text 4', 'woocommerce' );          
        } else {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-some-color">' . __( 'Text 5', 'woocommerce' );  
        }

        // Add closing div
        $stock_html .= '</div>';

        // Output
        echo $stock_html;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 10, 0 );
```

---

**CSS:** Add to an external style sheet, your CSS theme file or via a plugin

```css
.custom-stock-green {
    color: green;
}

.custom-stock-orange {
    color: #f2cd00;
}

.custom-stock-red {
    color: red;
}

.custom-stock-some-color {
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i recomend refactoring your code because your "logic" is correct, but your semantic is no so god.

1 - define type for return `$product->get_stock_quantity()`

2 - In php type number is equivalent to string too (because as dynamic type)

3 - Verify that `$product->get_stock_quantity()` return value when list has empty

Answer (score 0):

OMG Thanks a lot 7uc1f3r and thanks to all for your reply and participation.

I tryed your code and it's work like a charm. I didn't know how to just replace the default stock status.

I just added CSS for the single procut page because the custom color was not taken just cause the different class (stock.custom-stock-color)

This is the final code adapted for my site:

***********************************************************PHP****************************************

```
  // Change availability text - Single product page
function change_stock_text( $text, $product ) { 
    // Managing stock enabled
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {

        // Get stock status
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if ( $stock_quantity == 0 ) {
            $text = __( 'Rupture', 'woocommerce' );
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1 && $stock_quantity < 100 ) {
            $text = __( 'En stock', 'woocommerce' );          
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 100 && $stock_quantity < 1000 ) {
            $text = __( 'Livraison sous 7 jour', 'woocommerce' );          
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1000 && $stock_quantity < 2000 ) {
            $text = __( 'Livraison sous 1 mois', 'woocommerce' );          
        } else {
            $text = __( 'Reliqua fournisseur', 'woocommerce' );          
        }
    }

    // Output
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'change_stock_text', 10, 2 );

// Change availability class - Single product page
function change_stock_class( $class, $product ) {   
    // Managing stock enabled
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {

        // Get stock status
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if ( $stock_quantity == 0 ) {
            $class = 'custom-stock-red';
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1 && $stock_quantity < 100 ) {
            $class = 'stock custom-stock-green';         
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 100 && $stock_quantity < 1000 ) {
            $class = 'stock custom-stock-orange';         
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1000 && $stock_quantity < 2000 ) {
            $class = 'stock custom-stock-blueviolet';            
        } else {
            $class = 'stock custom-stock-purple';     
        }
    }

    // Output    
    return $class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_class', 'change_stock_class', 10, 2 );

// Add html - Shop/Category page
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    global $product;

    // Managing stock enabled
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ) {

        // Get stock status
        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if ( $stock_quantity == 0 ) {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-red">' . __( 'Rupture', 'woocommerce' );
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1 && $stock_quantity < 100 ) {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-green">' . __( 'En stock', 'woocommerce' );      
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 100 && $stock_quantity < 1000 ) {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-orange">' . __( 'Livraison sous 7 jours', 'woocommerce' );  
        } elseif ( $stock_quantity >= 1000 && $stock_quantity < 2000 ) {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-blueviolet">' . __( 'Livraison sous 1 mois', 'woocommerce' );          
        } else {
            $stock_html = '<div class="custom-stock-purple">' . __( 'Reliqua fournisseur', 'woocommerce' );  
        }

        // Add closing div
        $stock_html .= '</div>';

        // Output
        echo $stock_html;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 10, 0 );
```

************************CSS***********************

```
/*loop page > Custom stock status color */
.custom-stock-red {
    color: red;
}

.custom-stock-green {
    color: green;
}

.custom-stock-orange {
    color: #f4a400;
}

.custom-stock-blueviolet {
    color: blueviolet;
}

.custom-stock-purple {
    color: purple;
}

/*single product page > Custom stock status color */
.stock.custom-stock-red {
    color: red !important;
}

.stock.custom-stock-green {
    color: green !important;
}

.stock.custom-stock-orange {
    color: #f2cd00 !important;
}

.stock.custom-stock-blueviolet {
    color: blueviolet !important;
}

.stock.custom-stock-purple {
    color: purple !important;
}
```

*****************************THANK YOU AGAING*******************************